# Alljoyn framework Raspberry Pi and Alljoyn Android application are not interacting with each other?

Tags: alljoyn

Using Alljoyn framework I have developed an Android application to communicate with Raspberry Pi which also contains Alljoyn framework. I tried using the method which is available in the official site. But they are not communicating with each other.

I tried to run samples which are available from Alljoyn framework. I assumed my Raspberry Pi as server so I moved to this directory

```
export AJ_ROOT=`pwd`

# &lt;TARGET CPU&gt; can be either x86_64, x86, or whatever value you set for "CPU=" when running SCons.
export TARGET_CPU=arm

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$AJ_ROOT/core/alljoyn/build/linux/$TARGET_CPU/debug/dist/cpp/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


$AJ_ROOT/core/alljoyn/build/linux/$TARGET_CPU/debug/dist/cpp/bin/samples/chat -s mychannel
```

This is the tutorial for Alljoyn chat. Then I opened my Alljoyn chat Android application which I developed using Alljoyn SDKs, to make a chat with Raspberry Pi which is acting as server (s channel). But it's not getting connected.

This is the link for Android application chat:  https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/run-sample-apps/chat/android

Please kindly give some ideas how to do chat between Raspberry Pi and Android application through Alljoyn framework.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this gist](https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/30cfa7dfb041c12e6ba3) to compile alljoyn onto my raspberry pi.

After that you should be able to run the chat sample app with both the raspberry pi and the android device in the same network

Note that the folder structure may vary, depending on which Alljoyn SDK version you have.